# Make Gimp default for xcf files, not Krita

Tags: gimp, mime-type, krita

The default application for xcf is krita, not gimp.
How do I change this?
I see this in the MIME Type Editor:

[image: Mime]

Edit:

[image: rightclickproperties]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming Ubuntu, you can simply navigate to an xcf file and right-click it.
And select Properties (Ctrl+i) then **Open With** then **Set as Default**.

Comment: Right-click and Properties got me to File Type Options (above) and this did the trick.

Comment: Great. Please accept the answer (grey icons on the LHS) so other users can find your solution if they search for something similar.